# BNA install request timeout

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

So I've started hyperledger fabric following this tutorial:
https://medium.com/coinmonks/hyperledger-fabric-cluster-on-multiple-hosts-af093f00436

Everything seems to be working fine, but now I want to install my bna on it. 
I do it using command:

```
composer network install --card PeerAdmin@hlfv1 --archiveFile my-network@0.0.1.bna
```

But after some time I get request time out error:

```
Error: Error trying install business network. Error: No valid responses from any peers.
Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: REQUEST_TIMEOUT
Command failed
```

I've tried adding this to my peer's environment:

`- CORE_CHAINCODE_STARTUPTIMEOUT=1200s`

However, it seems that it had no effect and timeout occurs earlier than 1200s after the launch of command.

Also, I checked all of my container's docker logs but didn't find any errors.

I guess for some reason timeout time is either not being increased or there's some connection error while installing the network.

I expect bna to be installed just as in the tutorial. To be clear, if I install network as in the tutorial, everything works just fine, but now I need hyperledger fabric to run in different machines and use different peers.

Answer (score 0):

Hyperledger composer can't connect to the hyperledger fabric network.

I also had a lot of these issues.

My tip: Restart everything and try again.

This often resolves the problem. Hope this helps.

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

As a note, Composer is all but dead. We are no longer actively maintaining, or developing it. So changes to the Fabric codebase can have negative effects against Composer.